# undefined method when getting collection

Tags: collection

I had this block of code for long time but it suddenly stopped working:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model\ResourceModel\Campaign\Collection::getCollection()

My code is this:

```
 $campaignLimit = $this->_campaignCollection->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email)
            ->addFieldToFilter('event_name', 'Lost Basket')
            ->addFieldToFilter('sent_at', $updated)
            ->count();
```

All necessary classes are injected in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You already create collection object using **$this->_campaignCollection->create()**, No need to call again **->getCollection()**.

Try following way:

```
$campaignLimit = $this->_campaignCollection->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email)
            ->addFieldToFilter('event_name', 'Lost Basket')
            ->addFieldToFilter('sent_at', $updated)
            ->count();
```